# Mysql select counters grouped by time with gaps filled

Tags: mysql

I have [a query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b20f8/14) where I select some usage stats out of a table. It works fine but I need to also fill the gaps. The query groups by minute intervals but the empty minutes are ignored/not extracted.

Is there a way I could format this query to fill with a `0` the empty minutes?

Comment: Create a table with all the minutes you need and `LEFT JOIN` it to your result (whatever it is).  Use `COALESCE` to turn `NULL` into zero.

Comment: No other way besides this? I'm asking because the data I use is then projected into a chart that also requires the ability to group by hour, day and month.

Comment: There's also a solution to generate a temporary set of date values as a recursive CTE, but that's not supported by MySQL until version 8.0 (currently in release-candidate state).

Comment: I'm at an early stage so I could also switch to postgres. Would it support recursive CTE?

Comment: PostgreSQL has [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) as a standard SQL solution, and it also has [set-returning functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) as a nonstandard (PostgreSQL-only) solution.